# How to add PYTHONPATH to the .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, macos

I want to add a commend .bashrc file to import local python modules into the environment.

Here is the command where I paste it into the terminal, it works, but when I add it to the .bashrc file, it fails. 
Can someone help me with it?

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/jan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: It's fine. macOS terminal emulators, though, start *login* shells, which means `.bash_profile` is sourced, not `.bashrc` (unless you explicitly source `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```sh
if [[ $- = *i* ]] && [[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ]]; then source "$HOME/.bashrc"; fi
```

This ensures that on a login shell (which your terminal emulator is requesting), when the profile is read, it checks for [interactivity](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shells) and whether you have a non-zero `~/.bashrc` file. If so, source it.

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> An **interactive** shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless `-s` is specified) and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by [**isatty**(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)), or one started with the `-i` option. `PS1` is set and `$-` includes `i` if `bash` is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.

Comment: `[[ $_ = *i* ]]` is a better way to test for an interactive shell; `$PS1` is only *used* by interactive shells, but might still be present in the environment.

Comment: that's fair. it's a bashism but this is bash. (I try to avoid bashisms.) Anybody in an interactive shell without `$PS1` is asking for trouble, but it is indeed technically possible.

Comment: Now that I'm looking: the official GNU bash manual [states](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) testing for `$PS1` is a valid alternative and that the `$PS1` variable is guaranteed at shell startup (though it can be manually unset).

Comment: Yes, but it's not guaranteed to be *absent* in a non-interactive shell (especially as someone might unnecessarily export it). `$_`, on the other hand, contains `i` if and *only* if the shell is interactive.

Comment: There's no reference to `$_` (dollar underscore) in the bash manuals. I believe you mean `$-` (dollar hyphen), but that's a good point too.

Comment: yes, agreed, I've been relying on `$-` for interactive tests (and other options) for a long time. Definilely true of `ksh`, and petty sure `bash` has that too. AH, just confirmed in `ksh`, `$_` is the previous command in the cmd-line buffer.